# Is it possible to have multiple checkboxes in the same 'if' statement?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I'm very new to coding and am currently learning C#. More specifically I'm currently struggling with using checkboxes in group boxes. What I'm wondering is if it's possible to have multiple checkboxes in the same 'if' statement?

What I mean by is that, instead of just (for example):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, Eventargs e)
{
  float optionACheckBox = 149.00f;

  if (checkBox1.Checkstate == CheckState.Checked)
  {
     finalPrice = (optionACheckBox + 60)
  }
  MessageBox.Show(finalPrice);
}
```

how would I make it so that instead it would be something like:

```
if (checkBox1 & checkBox2 = CheckState.Checked)
{
 ((Value of checkBox1) + (Value of checkBox2) + 60)
}
```

where if the user checks checkBox1 & checkBox2 then both values can be used in the equation?

Regarding this, would it also be possible to make code that checks if any/what combination of the CheckBoxes in the GroupBox have been checked? Rather than me writing an 'if' statement for every single combination of the different CheckBoxes?

Thank you to anyone who takes the time to read this and for any tips given

More Context (Sorry this is my second ever StackOverFlow post so I'm not very good at proper formatting):

- Using Visual Studio 2019
- There are three CheckBoxes in total, and all three are in one GroupBox
- The CheckBoxes and GroupBox were added to the form using the toolbox feature

Comment: Change it like so `if (checkBox1. Checkstate && checkBox2.Checkstate = CheckState.Checked)`. Note `&&` (logical `AND`) not `&` which is BITWISE And.

Comment: Please rename your controls after you drop them on a form. No one  here wants to debug an obfuscated haze of button54, textbox27.. and in a month's time you won't either; tripping into the forms designer to check whether it's combobox46 or combobox64 that is the gender dropdown is far more wearisome than taking 2 seconds to call the control `genderComboBox` in the first place

Comment: *Note && (logical AND) not & which is BITWISE And* - it doesn't matter in this case

Comment: @zaitsman, that's not completely true. In VB.NET, `AndAlso` is the short-circuiting Boolean operator, while `And` is both the non-short-circuiting Boolean operator and the bitwise operator. In C#, `&&` is 100% equivalent to `AndAlso` and `&` is 100% equivalent to `And`. That means that, while you're right that `&&` should be used because you should always short-circuit unless you explicitly don't want to, `&` would still work because whether or not the code short-circuits makes no difference. Similarly, `||` and `|` in C# are 100% equivalent to `OrEsle` and `Or` in VB.NET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't really tell us much about your logic but it seems like you want a hypothetical scenario like:

- some fixed base price of the pizza
- a price for each topping
- a fixed price for applying any number of toppings

As such I'd look at accumulation:

```
float price = 100;

if(anchoviesCheckbox.Checked)
  basePrice += 20;

if(olivesCheckbox.Checked)
  basePrice += 30;

if(chilliesCheckbox.Checked)
  basePrice += 40;

//if anchovies AND chillies are chosen there is a surcharge because the most of the chefs are allergic to this combination and we have to get the manager to do it
if(anchoviesCheckbox.Checked && chilliesCheckBox.Checked)
  basePrice += 50;

//if any one OR more topping has been applied, there is a surcharge
if(anchoviesCheckbox.Checked || olivesCheckbox.Checked || chilliesCheckbox.Checked)
  basePrice += 60;
```

These accumulate because there is no `else` - if the checkbox is checked, cost is added to the final price. Each checkbox is viewed in isolation. Later some also act in combination.

Note you could of course also check if the base price is greater than 100 to know if to apply a surcharge..

---

Once you've got that clear in your mind how it works, you can save yourself some of those `if`s by treating the checkboxes in the group box as a collection

You can do this in the form constructor:

```
//put the prices in the checkbox Tag:

anchoviesCheckbox.Tag = 20;

olivesCheckbox.Tag = 30;

chilliesCheckbox.Tag = 20;
```

Then in your price calc method you can do something like:

```
float basePrice = 100:

foreach(var cb in toppingsGroupBox.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(cb => cb.Checked))
  basePrice += (int)cb.Tag;
```

This uses LINQ to pull out just the checked checkboxes, and then extract the price from their tag and add it on. You could even do:

```
float basePrice = 100 +
  toppingsGroupBox.Controls
    .OfType<CheckBox>()
    .Where(cb => cb.Checked)
    .Sum(cb => (int)cb.Tag);
```

For your adding a surcharge if any topping is chosen:

```
if(toppingsGroupBox.Controls
    .OfType<CheckBox>()
    .Any(cb => cb.Checked)))
basePrice += 60;
```

You could now add 100 different toppings checkboxes to the form and so long as you put the price in the tag there is no more code needs adding to the method that calculates the price

The "manager must add anchovies and chillies" surcharge could also be done with LINQ. For that you'd have to define a custom set of checkboxes and if they are all ticked then apply the surcharge:

```
class PizzaForm:Form{

  CheckBox[] managerSurcharge;

  PizzaForm() { // constructor

    ...
    managerSurcharge = new[]{ anchoviesCheckBox, chilliesCheckBox };

  }
```

Then in the price:

```
if(managerSurcharge.All(cb => cb.Checked))
  basePrice += 50;
```

Not an `if` in sight!  (yeah, it's really hard to do away with every if..)

But do name your controls and variables well; this code here is easily readable and obvious what it does because of the names. That manager surcharge scenario would be a lot more confusing if you write:

```
CheckBox array1 = new[]{ checkbox12, checkbox7 }
```

Comment: @Caius Thank You! Your answer is amazing.Regarding the accumulation, is it still possible to use an `else`? This is because I want it so that if the user doesn't select any of the CheckBoxes but still presses the Calculate button then text would come up prompting them to do so. Also regarding the base price, would it still be possible to use what you've recommended without one? because I want it so that the only fixed cost is the 60 to the order total, cause it would act as a CallOut fee for when a service is ordered, and it wouldn't be charged if the user doesn't order a service?

Comment: *is it still possible to use an else?* - you can, sure - eg "if topping selected add 20, else add 5", but if you have "if topping1 elseif topping2" it means that selecting topping 1 won't charge for topping 2; an "if if if" means every one is checked, an "if elseif elseif" means as soon as one matches the others stop being checked - this might be valid (perhaps you only want to charge for the boost expensive topping then the rest are free; do "if elseif elseif" in order from most expensive to least

Comment: *if the user doesn't select any of the CheckBoxes but still presses the Calculate button then text would come up prompting them to do so* - personally I would do this at the start before I even try and calculate a price. It's either `if(!anchovies.Checked && !olives.Checked && !chillies.Checked) MessageBox... return` so if they didn't choose any then you give a message and return. In linq terms that would be `if(groupBox.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().All(cb => !cb.Checked))` ie in plain English "in group box, controls of type checkbox, are they all not checked?"Then messagebox and `return`.."

Comment: *would it still be possible to use what you've recommended without one?* - sure, set it to 0. You have to give locally declared variables some value before you use them, and 0 is as acceptable as any other value. Do have to point out though that because you're not allowing a situation where none of the checkboxes are checked, then there must be at least one service that is checked, so the 60 is always charged?

Comment: @Caius In this case the 60 is a call-out/delivery fee added to the total cost of the toppings that the user orders. Also I didn't realize I wasn't allowing a situation in which none of the checkboxes are checked, as I want that to be possible. How would I make it so it is?

Comment: @Caius I forgot to actually say what my logic was (I assume logic means what the code is for/is doing?) which is that the user is deciding if they want to order a plumbing service from a plumbing company's website, the user has 3 options to choose from and they are able to pick more than one at a time (ie. they can either choose one of the options, two or all three). Then the user would be charged a $60 call out fee on top of the total cost of the order(s) they chose. If the total is equal/exeeds $300 then they get a 5% discount, same if they are a loyalty customer, but never at the same time

Comment: *Also I didn't realize I wasn't allowing a situation in which none of the checkboxes are checked, as I want that to be possible. How would I make it so it is?* - my musing on the requirement came from your earlier comment *This is because I want it so that if the user doesn't select any of the CheckBoxes but still presses the Calculate button then text would come up prompting them to do so*; If the user selects no checkboxes you can either let them do it (quote them 0?Or is there other stuff in the quote anyway?) or prohibit it with the code frags given in my comment above starting *if the..*

Comment: In essence, and it's a common pattern in programming; if you start your method by running loads of checks that `return` from the method if something is wrong, then the rest of the method isn't executed if the checks didn't pass: `if(age<18){ MessageBox.Show("Must be 18 to use this"); return;}`, `if(credcard == null) { MessageBox.Show("Nee dto have a credit card on file to use this"); return; }` - with this pattern of "check and reject" by the time you come to use proper calcs you know youre good to just use the data passed in because its already been sorted out to be correct

Comment: *If the total is equal/exeeds $300 then they get a 5% discount, same if they are a loyalty customer, but never at the same time* - this is a good elseif situation: `if(groupBox.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().All(cb => cb.Checked)) price *= 0.95; //give discount for all 3`, `else if(customer.IsLoyal) price *= 0.95; //loyal cust get 5%` `else if (price >= 300) price *= 0.95` - could also do with `||` "or" - `if(groupBox.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().All(cb => cb.Checked)) || customer.IsLoyal || price >= 300) price *= 0.95;` - choose whatever's readable; `||` lines get long, but `elseif` is repetitive

Comment: The solution to those is usually to store the results in well named variables: `var allServicesDiscount = groupBox.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().All(cb => cb.Checked)`, `var isLoyalDiscount = customer.StartDate < DateTime.Now.AddYears(-5) && customer.TotalSpend > 1000`, `var isHighpriceDiscount = price > Config.GetDiscountPriceLevel()`, then you can readbly write `if(allServicesDiscount || isLoyalDiscount || isHighpriceDiscount) price *= 0.95` - the variable names document the code for you, and it reads like a book

Comment: sorry for the late reply but I just wanna say thanks for all the help you've given me! @Caius

Comment: You're most welcome, glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can't compare the `checkbox` itself with a `CheckState` so you have to use `checkBox1.CheckState == CheckState.Checked` or better using Boolean "Checked" property: `if(checkBox1.Checked)` which will check if the checkbox is checked.

As for your last Question on how to detect if any checkbox is checked you can use `||` the logical "OR" Operator:

```
if(checkBox1.Checked || checkBox2.Checked || checkBox3.Checked)
```

**Update**

**Logical Operator vs Conditional Short Circuit Operator**

1. Logical Operator: `&` is used to ensure all Operands are evaluated and checked.
2. Conditional Short Circuit Operator: `&&` is used to skip the right side Operand.

As mentioned in the comments, both will work in the vast majority of the cases, but I would always use the "Conditional Short Circuit Operators" when possible, to skip the unnecessary Check of the right side Operand.

Comment: *what you meant to use is the logical "And" Operator && which will return true if all inputs are true* - it doesn't really matter for this case. Don't imply it's wrong to use &, just explain the difference if you want to make a point of it

Comment: `&` is the bitwise AND operator but it is also the non-short-circuiting Boolean AND operator, so it will work in the vast majority of cases that `&&` works. While it is correct that you should use `&&` in the vast majority of cases because you should always short-circuit by default, `&` will still work if short-circuiting makes no difference, which is the case here.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, you are both correct. I updated the Answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`switch case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements) judgments to assign different outcomes to these different choices.

But because every combination is a judgment situation, no matter what judgment method you use, you need to judge them separately.

The judgment to judge that both are selected should be as follows:

```
 if (checkBox1.Checked && checkBox2.Checked)
            {
                //To do something
            }
```

Some documents:
[checked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checked?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#system-windows-forms-checkbox-checked) 、[&&](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/logical-and-operator-amp-amp?view=msvc-170)、[||](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/logical-or-operator-pipe-pipe?view=msvc-170)、[== and !=](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/equality-operators-equal-equal-and-exclpt-equal?view=msvc-170)